# Javascript object unique ID with variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use a unique ID to store a JSON object in an array so that I can pull out that specific object at a later date in my code, however my expected output isn't happening:

```js
var applications = []

var key = 50

var obj = {
  key: {
    "name": "John"
  }
}

// expected output:
//
// [{
//   '50': {
//     "name": "John"
//   }
// }]
// 

applications.push(obj)
```

Comment: You've hardcoded the property name `key`, see [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Examples).

Answer (score 4):

In order to use a dynamic key, we just need to wrap that key in square brackets `[]` like:

```js
var applications = []
var key = 50
var obj = {
  [key]: {
    "name": "John"
  }
}
applications.push(obj)

console.log(applications)
```

Comment: Did not know about the square bracket method to use a string as the name of the key, thanks for that!

Comment: Note: it is not working on ES5

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[]` is available from **ES6** and **Babel** and not **ES5**

For compatibility you need to make the object first, then use `[]` to set it.

```
var key = 50;
var obj = {};
obj[key] = someValueArray;
applications.push(obj);
```